# Do homotopy colimits always commute with homotopy colimits?

Tags: triangulated-categories, homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, ct.category-theory

Do homotopy colimits commute with homotopy colimits? The setting I am thinking of is that of a triangulated category with a model, but it would be interesting to have more general answers as well. A good reference would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  See theorem 24.9 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110316).  Here's a [somewhat less abstract reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=LOlPi21-T_8C&lpg=PA59&ots=wCJA3z6atV&dq=homotopy%2520colimits%2520commute%2520with%2520one%2520another&pg=PA60#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Ah, it was a few years ago when the answer was posted, but it turns out this is exactly what I was looking for right now. Thank you!

For those who want to use this in their papers, let me just leave a remark here that it was published as part of Memoir of AMS, Vol 155, No. 736 (2002).

